# Jenkins Git parameter failed to get branch when using multiple gitlab repo

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins pipeline which is stored on gitlab so I'm using Pipeline script from SCM to execute it,
Now the problem is I'm trying to use the git parameter and retrieve branches from a different repository.
I didn't add to the repository  as I just need to get the branches so no checkout is needed.
Under Configure System I have set the Git lab connection to the second repository which needed to retrieve branches and I'm using this in the pipeline setting.

Bottom line is that it's doesn't work, can you advice what am I doing wrong ?
I did found similar questions but not same issue as I have

```
The default value has been returned  
No Git repository configured in SCM configuration or plugin is configured wrong  
Option 'Use repository' is set as: 'https://XXX'  
Please check the configuration
```